# Dictionary app not responding yet

Tags: android, mysql, dictionary

[main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKtYj.png)

I wrote a dictionary app and save it in text file in Row because I couldn't work with apijexcel the main problem is app not responding yet. I created database mysql, class read data from text file, class with 2 constructors word & translation, adapter class for listview item.

I don't know what is the main error in code.
any help please?

```
    public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<WordTranslation> AllTranslations= new ArrayList<WordTranslation>();
    private DictionaryDataBaseHelper myDictionaryDatabaseHelper;
    TextView Translation_textview;
    TextView Word_textview;
    public Adapter (Context context , ArrayList<WordTranslation>AllTranslations){
        this.context=context;
        this.AllTranslations=AllTranslations;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return AllTranslations.size() ;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return AllTranslations.get(i);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return  position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        AllTranslations = myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getAllWords();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_item, null);
        Translation_textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trans3);
        Word_textview= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.word3);
        Translation_textview.setText(AllTranslations.get(position).translation);
        Word_textview.setText(AllTranslations.get(position).word);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**WordTranslation Class**

```
    public class WordTranslation {
    String word, translation;
    //constractor with 2params
    public WordTranslation(String word, ArrayList<String> AllTranslation) {
        this.word = word;

        // StringBuilder equals to String decleration as well as StringBuffered
       //  JavaTpoint website

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (String string : AllTranslation)
            stringBuilder.append(string);

            stringBuilder.insert(translation.length() , "/ ") ;
        this.translation = stringBuilder.toString();

    }

    public WordTranslation(String word, String AllTranslation) {
        this.word = word;
        this.translation = AllTranslation;
    }
}
```

**DictionaryDataBaseHelper Class**

```
    public  class DictionaryDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    final static String Dictionary_DataBase = "Dictionary";
    final static String ID_ITEM_COLUMN = "id";
    final static String WORD_COLUMN = "word";
    final static String TRANSLATION_COLUMN = "translation";
    final static String CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + Dictionary_DataBase + "(" +
            ID_ITEM_COLUMN + "INTEGER PRAMARY KEY COLUMN , " +
            WORD_COLUMN + "TEXT ," +
            TRANSLATION_COLUMN + "TEXT )";
    final static String ON_UPGRADE_QUERY = "DROP TABLE" + Dictionary_DataBase;
    Context context;
    public DictionaryDataBaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, Dictionary_DataBase, factory, version);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(ON_UPGRADE_QUERY);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public long insertData(WordTranslation wordTranslation) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(WORD_COLUMN, wordTranslation.word);
        values.put(TRANSLATION_COLUMN, wordTranslation.translation);
        return database.insert(Dictionary_DataBase, null, values);
    }
    public long updateData(WordTranslation wordTranslation) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(WORD_COLUMN, wordTranslation.word);
        values.put(TRANSLATION_COLUMN, wordTranslation.translation);
        return database.update(Dictionary_DataBase, values, WORD_COLUMN + "=?", new String[]{wordTranslation.word});
    }
    public void DeleteData(WordTranslation wordTranslation) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String QueryString = "DELETE FROM" + Dictionary_DataBase + "WHERE" + WORD_COLUMN + " = ' " + wordTranslation.word + "'";
        database.execSQL(QueryString);
    }
    public ArrayList<WordTranslation> getAllWords() {
        ArrayList<WordTranslation> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String SelectAllQueryString = "SELECT * FROM " + Dictionary_DataBase;
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(SelectAllQueryString, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                WordTranslation wordTranslation = new WordTranslation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRANSLATION_COLUMN)));
                arrayList.add(wordTranslation);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
    public WordTranslation getWordTranslation(String word) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        WordTranslation wordTranslation = null;
        String SelectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM " + Dictionary_DataBase + "WHERE " + WORD_COLUMN + "  = ' " + word + " '";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(SelectQueryString, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            wordTranslation = new WordTranslation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRANSLATION_COLUMN)));
        }
        return wordTranslation;
    }
    public WordTranslation getWordTranslation(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        WordTranslation wordTranslation = null;
        String SelectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM " + Dictionary_DataBase + "WHERE " + ID_ITEM_COLUMN + "  = ' " + id + " '";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(SelectQueryString, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            wordTranslation = new WordTranslation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TRANSLATION_COLUMN)));
        }
        return wordTranslation;
    }
    public void InitialDBForFrist(ArrayList<WordTranslation> wordTranslations) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL("BEGIN");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        for (WordTranslation wordTranslation : wordTranslations) {
            values.put(WORD_COLUMN, wordTranslation.word);
            values.put(TRANSLATION_COLUMN, wordTranslation.translation);
            database.insert(Dictionary_DataBase, null, values);
        }
        database.execSQL("COMMIT");
    }
}
```

**DictionaryLoader Class**

```
    public class DictionaryLoader {
    public static void loadData(BufferedReader bufferedReader, DictionaryDataBaseHelper dictionaryDataBase) {
        ArrayList<WordTranslation> allwords = new ArrayList<WordTranslation>();
            allwords = new ArrayList<WordTranslation>();
            BufferedReader fileReader = bufferedReader;
            int c = 17;
            try {
                c = fileReader.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (c != (-1)) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((char) c != '\n' && c != -1) {
                        stringBuilder.append((char) c);
                        System.out.println(stringBuilder.length());
                        try {
                            c = fileReader.read();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (c == -1) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }`String wordString = stringBuilder.toString();
    ArrayList <String> translate = new ArrayList<String>();
             while (c!= '\n' || c!= '\t')  ;
                try {
                    c= fileReader.read();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (c == '\n' || c== '\t' || c == '\r') {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
    while (c != '\n') {
        stringBuilder1.append((char) c);
        try {
            c = fileReader.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String translateString = stringBuilder1.toString();
        translate.add(translateString);
    }
    }else {
                    break;
                }
                wordString = wordString.trim();
             allwords.add( new WordTranslation(wordString , translate));
            }
        try {
        dictionaryDataBase.InitialDBForFrist(allwords);
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Define "not responding". 2. What's the error?

Comment: Please, design your question properly. Read here about that [Asking good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Don't post screenshot of your code. Insert code itself here.
And share your error as it is shown on your screen. I can't even understand what are database1, 2, 3 and those loader1, looader2. Please clear your question.

Comment: no error appears, just dialog box about app not responding.

Comment: @hendahmed, maybe you are reading your txt file in the main thread(UI thread), that's why it takes a long time, and Android after 5 seconds of not responding main threads thinks that app is not responding asking users to choose what to do, wait or close. You need to read txt file in another thread. Maybe AsyncTask will help you

Comment: is AsyncTask for catch any data?! i released it for catching data from server only.

Comment: @hendahmed, I guess you are not familiar with Threads in Android. And moreover in Java. So you first need to read about Multitasking, Threading in Java, and then learn their implementation in Android. Shortly use Thread when you do some complicated work like reading-writing from a server, from sd card, and of course from the txt file. And AsyncTask is one of the classes that allow you to create thread + do something on UI thread after thread is finished. You can read this blog post about [AsynctTask](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily happening because you are trying to parse a `text` file line-by-line so as to get to the `meaning` and the `translation` eventually and therefore this is taking a time more than 5 seconds which is in turn blocking the app's UI thread and you get to see the dreaded `Application not responding` or `ANR` dialog.

I would rather goad you to create an `SQLITE` db where you can store your `meaning` and `translation` and eventually work around with convention `queries` to get to your expected results.

Comment: is there any tutorial to earn this experience please?